# Pipe grep search result into sed replace

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I'm writing a script to update the hosts file with the current dynamic address. I get the address from ifconfig and use sed to update /etc/hosts.

```
#following returns the current VPN address e.g. 10.8.0.14
ifconfig | grep -oP 'inet addr:\K(.*)?(?=  P-t-P)'

#following can be used to replace the original one with the VPN address
sudo sed -i 's/127.0.1.1/{new address}/g' /etc/hosts
```

But how do I pipe the output of the grep into the replace text {new address} in sed? Is it possible to do this on one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution):

```
sudo sed -i "s/127.0.1.1/$(ifconfig | grep -oP 'inet addr:\K(.*)?(?=  P-t-P)')/g" /etc/hosts
```